# How to create a Trigger that can insert a foreign key value from table B to table A

Tags: mysql

```sql
CREATE DATABASE Ebooks;

CREATE TABLE Usuario (
     Email VARCHAR (320) PRIMARY KEY, 
     NombreUsuario VARCHAR (70), 
     Contrasena VARCHAR (20), 
     Nombre VARCHAR (30), 
     Apellido VARCHAR (30), 
     IdDireccion INT, 
     FechaNac DATE, 
     Sexo VARCHAR (1), 
     Celular BIGINT, 
     IdPreferencias INT, 
     IdTarjeta INT
);

CREATE TABLE Direccion (
     IdDireccion INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
     CalleyNumero VARCHAR (120), 
     Colonia VARCHAR (30), 
     CP INT, 
     Ciudad VARCHAR (30), 
     Estado VARCHAR (20), 
     Pais VARCHAR  (20)
);
```

I want to create an AFTER INSERT ON Direccion Trigger that allows me to take Direccion.IdDireccion value and insert it into Usuario.IdDireccion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keyword `NEW` after inserting the value on `Direccion` table, for example:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trg_insert_usuario AFTER INSERT ON Direccion
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `Usuario` 
    VALUES('random', '1234', '1234', '6532', '12345', NEW.IdDireccion,
          '123', '12', '1234', '124', '1234');
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I'm trying something like this:
CREATE TRIGGER fkiddire AFTER INSERT ON direccion 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
UPDATE usuario SET IdDireccion=(SELECT NEW.IdDireccion FROM Direccion);
END;

Comment: What's your basis while updating the `IdDireccion` of `Usuario`? I mean you should have a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I have two tables: Usuario and Direccion. After inserting a value into IdDireccion in Direccion table I want a trigger that can Update my NULL column IdDireccion from Usuario table with the same value as IdDireccion from table Direccion.

Comment: You should have a primary key in `Usuario` table.

Answer (score 0):

See [20.3.1 Trigger Syntax and Examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html) for reference.

You'll need something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_dir AFTER INSERT ON Direccion
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO Usuario SET IdDireccion=NEW.IdDireccion
```

Although that will insert a new row where all fields except `IdDireccion` are null, in particular the primary key for `Usuario` should be included in the `INSERT` statement too.

---

Update as per the below comment:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_dir AFTER INSERT ON Direccion
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE Usuario SET IdDireccion=NEW.IdDireccion WHERE Email=<THE EMAIL>
```

Comment: I have two tables: Usuario and Direccion. After inserting a value into IdDireccion in Direccion table I want a trigger that can Update my NULL column IdDireccion from Usuario table with the same value as IdDireccion from table Direccion.

Comment: @RicardoRuizMelendez to do that you'll use an `UPDATE` instead of an `INSERT`, and a `WHERE` clause to update only the relevant row from `Usuario`, i.e., you'll have to include the field `Usuario.Email` for that particular row, which you must have *somehow*. See updated answer.

Comment: The thing is I won't know any value until the User inserts it. Imagine it's a sign up for any website.

Comment: @RicardoRuizMelendez in such case you'll be inserting into both tables at once, so you *should* have the key to look for available.